# paillier image encryption in python

Tags: python, image, encryption, paillier

I have tried to encrypt an image using paillier. But I can't decrypt it. Please help me to findout.

```
from phe import paillier
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import PIL
import numpy
openfilename = "greyscale.png"
img2 = cv2.imread(openfilename,0)
public_key, private_key = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair()
encrypted_number_list = [[public_key.encrypt(int(x)) for x in row] for row 
in img2]
encrypted_number_array = numpy.array(encrypted_number_list)
print(encrypted_number_array)
decrypted_number_list =[private_key.decrypt(x) for x in 
encrypted_number_array]
decrypted_number_array = numpy.array(decrypted_number_list)
print(decrypted_number_array)
```

Here is the image I am using:

[image]

Comment: I got the following errors when I run it.
TypeError: Expected encrypted_number to be an EncryptedNumber not: <class 
'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Can you share `greyscale.png`?

Comment: I have shared the greyscale image

Comment: I don't know `paillier` but the line starting `encrypted_number_list = ...` looks wrong to me. I don't believe the image you read in using OpenCV has the concept of `rows` that you are trying to iterate over. I think I would just do a simple `read()` of the entire PNG file rather than `imread()` and pass that data to the encryptor. Then you can do an `imdecode()` after decryption to get a displayable image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell OpenCV image can be represented as a list of lists. So you can iterate over it.

Comment: @Alderven I was not aware of that, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image encryption/decryption with [pailer](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
import cv2
from phe import paillier
from scipy.misc import toimage

img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)
public_key, private_key = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair()
data_encrypted = [[public_key.encrypt(int(x)) for x in row] for row in img]

data_decrypted = [[private_key.decrypt(x) for x in row] for row in data_encrypted]
toimage(data_decrypted).save('result.png')
```

Comment: @ Alderven thankyou for your reply. Is there any fast method for Paillier image encryption

Comment: This is actually very very slow process for a large image

Comment: Try fully homomorphic encryption implementations such as TenSEAL. They can encrypt & decrypt tensors and an image is actually a tensor. It will be performed much faster.